# Wavy corners when printing calibration cat

Tags: print-quality

I've recently set up my Snapmaker 2.0 A350 again after moving apartments. I started by calibrating it. There was a couple of issues I'm familiar with that I could solve but one I don't know what to do about.

The corners of my CaliCat are wavy, the best I can describe them.

[image: Printed model of CaliCat with wavy sections throughout the print]

I'm using Cura as my slicer and the Snapmaker's filament. I know they're not good but I got it with the printer and want to finish it on less important jobs. My thermometer for the nozzle might be wrong, I was getting "elephant's foot" and drags marks in the bottom layer until I lowered the temperature to 180 °C. If I lower it to 175-170 °C, the prints fail. The rest of the settings are on default from Generic PLA and I'm using the Snapmaker profile that Cura came with.

Comment: It looks like you might have loose belts, and/or Z wobble from problems with a lead screw or how it's mounted. I'm not familiar with your printer so I'm not sure how plausible those are.

Comment: https://asset.conrad.com/media10/isa/160267/c1/-/sv/002350349PI00/image.jpg?x=600&y=600

This is how it looks.

Comment: What is the Z motion system based on? I can't really tell from the picture. Are there lead screws behind the vertical beams or belts or what?

Comment: Sadly i don't know but i will look into it and get back to you. The beams have a metal sheet to protect their insides from dust as the machine has an interchangable tool head , with the alternatives doing laser cutting and CNC.

Comment: Yes there indeed seems to be a screw on the inside. I'll disassemble and maintain all of them on the weekend and get back here with how it went. 

https://forum.snapmaker.com/t/beware-of-loose-lead-screw-nut-fasteners/2505

Comment: OK, if there are Z lead screws it's very likely a problem with the screws or how they're mounted. If they're not perfectly straight or if they're overconstrained or similar, they can apply tension in different directions in the XY plane as they turn, causing this kind of wavy effect. You could measure the wavelength and see if it matches the lead or pitch of the leadscrews.

Comment: The defect looks like Z wobble, this can be caused by the lead screw, check the internal guide rails and rollers, see [this video](https://youtu.be/L344lVpnoRg) for assembly/disassembly.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth measuring your heater-block and bed temperatures to verify that they are actually as far off as you believe.

1. The least expensive, but most difficult way is to use the thermocouple on a multimeter that can measure temperature.
2. Easier is to use a single point pyrometer for a non-contact measurement.
3. The easiest, but most expensive way to measure the temperatures, is to use a thermal imager that will tell you the highest temperature within the image.

Note: This is not the final answer, but too much for a comment.  Please do not let this discourage posting a final answer.

Comment: This is possible, but I would not expect such a severe effect from temperature variation unless the measurements are way off, to the point that it's underextruding from the temperature falling so low.

Comment: @GitHub True, but tweaking the temperature if it's not off just complicates finding the problem.  I put this as an answer because it is too long for a comment, and ill formatted in a comment.  I don't expect it to be the final answer.